# Implementing and typing Either in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement right biased Either type in Kotlin and I'm having issues with covariance in the flatmap declaration (Not in the implementations):

`Type parameter L is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type`

```kotlin
sealed class Either<out L, out R> {
    abstract fun isLeft(): Boolean
    abstract fun isRight(): Boolean

    abstract fun <R2> flatMap(f: (R) -> Either<L, R2>): Either<L, R2>

    fun <R2> map(f: (R) -> R2): Either<L, R2> = flatMap { Right(f(it)) }
}

data class Left<L>(val l: L): Either<L, Nothing>() {
    override fun isLeft(): Boolean = true
    override fun isRight(): Boolean = false

    override fun <R2> flatMap(f: (Nothing) -> Either<L, R2>): Either<L, R2> = this
}

data class Right<R>(val r: R): Either<Nothing, R>() {
    override fun isLeft(): Boolean = false
    override fun isRight(): Boolean = true

    override fun <R2> flatMap(f: (R) -> Either<Nothing, R2>): Either<Nothing, R2> = f(r)
}
```

Is it possible to solve it using typing? I prefer to not to fall in external functions with `when` clauses

Comment: As an aside, I would make `isLeft()` an abstract `val` rather than an abstract `fun` (same with `isRight()`).

Comment: Sidenote: If your circumstances allow you to use external libraries for the problem, I'd strongly recommend using arrow-kt for that (https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/either-and-ior/). Regardless if you can use that lib or not, you still might be able to learn a bit or two from their implementation of Either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Kotlin doesn't know how you are going to implement the abstract `flatMap` method. It doesn't go to every existing implementation to check if they are type-safe, which itself could be very difficult.

For example, you could implement `Either` like this, as an additional implementation.

```
class A {
    fun somethingSpecific() {}
}
class B

class SomethingElse: Either<A, Int>() {
    override fun isLeft() = true

    override fun isRight() = true

    override fun <R2> flatMap(f: (Int) -> Either<A, R2>): Either<A, R2> {
        val x = f(1)
        when (x) {
            is Left -> x.l.somethingSpecific()
            else -> {}
        }
        return Left(A())
    }

}
```

And you did:

```
val x: Either<Any, Int> = SomethingElse()
val y = x.flatMap { Left(B()) }
```

You would end up calling `somethingSpecific` on `B`.

In any case, the abstract method approach is not possible.

Use a generic extension to implement `flatMap` instead:

```
fun <L, R, R2> Either<L, R>.flatMap(f: (R) -> Either<L, R2>): Either<L, R2> =
    when (this) {
        is Left -> this
        is Right -> f(this.r)
    }
```

Note that the same trick with `SomethingElse` can't be done here. You can't add a third arm to the `when` with the implementation of `SomethingElse.flatMap`, because `L` and `R` are not constrained.

```
is SomethingElse -> {
    val x = f(1) // oops, f doesn't take an Int
    when (x) {
        is Left -> x.l.somethingSpecific() // oops, x.l is not A
        else -> {}
    }
    Left(A()) // oops, this should return Either<L, R2>, not Either<A, Nothing>
}
```

And if you *do* constrain them to `A` and `Int`, you won't be able to call `flatMap` on a `Either<Any, Int>`.